Regression models across a rolling window in Python
I want to perform regression models across a rolling window without explicitly iterating through each column and time period.
Is it possible to perform a regression on multi-dimensional data in a vectorized way to replace the rolling window loop (loop t) ? Maybe using tools like sklearn ?
Thank you for your help!
for column in range(0,len(returns.columns)):
    
    for t in range(rolling_window, len(returns)):
        
        end_date = t
    
        start_date = t - rolling_window
    
        y = returns.iloc[start_date:end_date, column]
        X_rolling = X.iloc[start_date:end_date]
        
        model = sm.OLS(y, X_rolling).fit()


There is a RollingOLS that you can use in stats:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.regression.rolling import RollingOLS
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame() # create instance of dataframe 
df["X"] = np.random.randn(100) # assign X
df["Y"] = 2*df["X"] + np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=100) # and Y as a function of X
windowSize = 10 # define the window size
rollingResults = RollingOLS.from_formula("Y ~ X", data=df, window=windowSize) # define the rolling OLS
model = rollingResults.fit() # fit the model
df["Fitted"] = model.params["Intercept"] + model.params["X"]*df["X"] # use the parameters
plt.scatter(df.index, df["Y"], label = "Raw data")
plt.plot(df["Fitted"], "r--", label = "Fitted")
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Index")
plt.ylabel("Y")

The results will look like this:

Notice the start where there are no points, those are the NaNs due to the rolling window. Hope this helps you further
